# Find which variables are free in underdetermined linear system

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sympy

I have an underdetermined system of linear equations. This can for example be solved by SimPy, where the solution is then a function of some free variables. What I am looking for is, which are those free variables. This set of variables is not unique but one option is enough. For example

```
[1  0  1] [x1] = [1]
[0  1  0] [x2] = [1]
          [x3]
```

Here, `x2` is determined by the second equation, and either `x1`or `x3` could be used as a free variable. So for example the set `{x1}` is a valid solution to my problem

One way of finding this is using SymPy and parsing the solutions to find which variables are used in there. This is rather cumbersome. Is there a nicer way to do this? Preferably without any symbolic computations (returning the index of the free variables).

Here the same question is asked, but not answered, as it turned out the asker wanted to ask something else: [How to determine which one is free variable in the result of sympy.linsolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510558/how-to-determine-which-one-is-free-variable-in-the-result-of-sympy-linsolve)

He just wanted a single solution to the system. I want to know the free variables, and don't even need to know a solution.

Comment: what is the equation for x3?

Comment: @EPo Sorry, my matrix was incorrect. I fixed it and now the comments underneath are correct. `x2 = 1` and `x1 + x3 = 1`, so either `x1` or `x3` can be chosen as free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to [How can I find a basis for the column space of a rectangular matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867494/how-can-i-find-a-basis-for-the-column-space-of-a-rectangular-matrix) except that you are asking for free variables, which correspond to the columns that remain after we picked a basis for the column space. So, the set difference reduces one problem to the other. Here is an example with a slightly more complicated matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lu
M = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 7, 0]])
U = lu(M)[2]
basis_columns = {np.flatnonzero(U[i, :])[0] for i in range(U.shape[0])}
free_variables = set(range(U.shape[1])) - basis_columns
```

Answer: `{1, 3}`.

Caveat: all this is sensitive to floating point errors, so SymPy could still be preferred if you have exact rational numbers in the input and want to preserve them as such.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is precise, but I think the free variable is any variable has non-zero coefficient for non-pivotal element in [echelon form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374133/linear-algebra-free-variables), and a variable it describes.